# Software to pad jpeg files

Tags: windows, software-rec

Is there any software to specify desired file size for the jpeg image, so it can pad bytes, in order to achieve desired size. So the original file size is smaller, I want to have exact size file, which is always bigger than the original.

Thx

Comment: *Why* would you want that? Also, does it have to be a jpeg? Can it be another image format?

Comment: it has to be jpeg and it requires for the tests on mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stenography methods increase file size.

http://lifehacker.com/230915/geek-to-live--hide-data-in-files-with-easy-steganography-tools

http://members.cox.net/ebmmd/stego/stego.html

Answer (score 1):

How big do you want the file to be? You can add Exif metadata to the file with apps for that purpose, such as [this one](http://exifpilot.com).

However, Exif metadata is restricted in size to 64 kB in JPEG images, so this method won't work unless the original image is more than 64 kB smaller than the desired size.

Comment: up to 2-5Mb. And since the original file resolution is small I can't make it very big, then decrease the size by compression.